# EclipseLink: "Updates are not allowed" on a native query INSERT INTO

Tags: mysql, jpa, eclipselink

since upgrading to EclipseLink 2.5 from EL 2.1 we get a PersistenceException on a previously running code.
The scenary is really simple: we have two identical tables, the only difference is that one is a "history" version of the other. Basically, when we are sure that a row won't change anymore, we move the row to the history table. This means that while the id is generated on the first table, it is "inherited" on the history table. Here are the entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DOCUMENT")
public class Document implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    // Some other fields
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "DOCUMENT_HISTORY")
public class DocumentHistory implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private long id;
    // Some other fields
}
```

In order to move a row to the history table we use a native query (because some columns are not mapped as fields in the entity classes):

```
String query = "INSERT INTO DOCUMENT_HISTORY SELECT * FROM DOCUMENT t WHERE t.id=?1";
Query updateQuery = entityManager.createNativeQuery(query);
updateQuery.setParameter(1, document.getId());
updateQuery.executeUpdate();
```

When executing this query, sometimes this exception is thrown:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-7251] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): 
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: The attribute [id] of class [org.myc.entities.jpa.company.DocumentHistory] is mapped to a primary key column in the database. Updates are not allowed.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.flush(EntityManagerImpl.java:868)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.performPreQueryFlush(QueryImpl.java:963)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeUpdate(QueryImpl.java:296)
    at org.myc.utility.jpa.user.DocumentManager.toDocumentHistory(DocumentManager.java:141)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-7251] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: The attribute [id] of class [org.myc.entities.jpa.company.DocumentHistory] is mapped to a primary key column in the database. Updates are not allowed.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException.primaryKeyUpdateDisallowed(ValidationException.java:2548)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.foundation.AbstractDirectMapping.writeFromObjectIntoRowWithChangeRecord(AbstractDirectMapping.java:1257)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildRowForUpdateWithChangeSet(ObjectBuilder.java:1768)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.updateObjectForWriteWithChangeSet(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:1030)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.UpdateObjectQuery.executeCommitWithChangeSet(UpdateObjectQuery.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.executeWriteWithChangeSet(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:301)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.WriteObjectQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(WriteObjectQuery.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:899)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:798)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWorkObjectLevelModifyQuery(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2896)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1793)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1775)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1726)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitChangedObjectsForClassWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitAllObjectsForClassWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitAllObjectsWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.writeAllObjectsWithChangeSet(AbstractSession.java:4196)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabase(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1441)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabaseWithPreBuiltChangeSet(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1587)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.writeChanges(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.flush(EntityManagerImpl.java:863)
    ... 5 more
```

Did anyone have the same problem? Why do you think this doesn't happen on all rows but only some of them (with no apparent specific characteristics)?
Thanks in advance,
Luc

P.S.: Is it correct for EL to perform mapping/query validation on a native query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem and it wasn't related at all with that query, so I still don't know why the exception is thrown there.
The problem was that instead of using `entityManager.find()` to get the newly inserted history row, we were creating a DocumentHistory instance (with same ID) which was not attached to a persistence context, then using that instance to perform other operations.
Hope it helps someone.

Comment: _"which was not attached to a persistence context"_ this is the side-effect of skipping transactional cache (persistence context) and shared cache by using INSERT statement I was mentioned in my comment above.

Comment: Thanks @wypieprz, I didn't understand that was what you where referring to.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in JPA 2.0 specification, `executeUpdate()` executes an update or delete statement thus insert is not supported.

You can insert an entity into the underlying database by persisting and flushing it with use of EntityManager (within a transaction). An dummy example in your particular case might look as follows:

```java
// transaction starts
Document doc = em.find(Document.class, id);
DocumentHistory docHistory = new DocumentHistory(doc);
em.persist(docHistory);
// transaction ends
```

**NOTE**: instead of a proprietary solution (which is fine) you may consider of using [EclipseLink's auditing](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Auditing) feature:

> *EclipseLink also support full history support, which allows a complete history of all changes made to the database to be tracked in a mirror history table.*

Comment: JPA 2.0 specification also states that `executeUpdate() throws IllegalStateException` for SELECT statements or for a criteria query. Also you can find a lot of examples everywhere using the executeUpdate with an INSERT statement. Therefore I don't believe that is the problem (or was EL 2.1 not JPA 2.0 compliant?).
I can't use the `persist()` because there are some table columns not mapped as fields, which won't be copied using this method.

Thanks for the auditing advice, I wasn't aware of its existence, however that is not what we use the history table for.

Comment: Yes, `SELECT` statement should be definitely used with `em.create*Query` methods. As for `executedUpdate`, indeed, it would be probably better and more adequate to describe INSERT as _discouraged_ rather than _not supported_. You can use `INSERT` (or even `ALTER`) with JPA but it entails inconsistency between cached entities and the database. Also you can prevent copying non-persistable fields by annotating them with `@Transient`, so `em.persist()` should not hurt your ORM.

Comment: Regarding the fields, the problem is inverse. Say that in the DB table there is a column named "type" but there is no field "type" mapping that column in the entity class. In order to copy that column value from the Document to the DocumentHistory I believe there is no other way than to use native SQL.

Comment: What prevents you from adding "type" field to the entity class?

Comment: Not knowing at compile time that there will be a "type" column :)